# cx_Oracle - Django ORM - Reference Count Increase

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, orm, cx-oracle

I have a Long Running Python Process that uses Django ORM against Oracle database.

The size of the process keeps on increasing steadily.

I was profiling this process using mem_top and i find that the reference count of one particular data type  increases continuously with iterations.

**Datatype is  [{u'time': u'0.004', u'sql': u'QUERY = u\'SELECT "RANGE_STATUS"."I**

**References increased from 534 to 53295**

This list seems to have almost all the queries that were executed using the ORM

Does this mean that there is a memory leak in the cx_Oracle module or somewhere in Django ORM?

Here is the memtop result between two iterations 10 minutes apart.

WARNING : 27/12/2014 05:45:46 PM :

```
refs:
9500    <type 'dict'> {'TAPE_DRIVE_FORMAT': -1610612736, 'SLE_ERROR': 1, 'IMAGE_REL_I386_SEC
8410    <type 'list'> [('200', '343045', 1321), ('200', '343046', 1322), ('200', '343047', 1
1578    <type 'dict'> {'logging.atexit': None, 'django.core.files.errno': None, 'django.test
1567    <type 'list'> ['mem_top', 'mem_top', 'datetime', 'datetime', 'sys', 'string', 'os', 
688 <type 'dict'> {'FILE_SYSTEM_ATTR': 2, 'GetDriveTypeW': <built-in function GetDriveTy
688 <type 'dict'> {'FILE_SYSTEM_ATTR': 2, 'GetDiskFreeSpaceEx': <built-in function GetDi
534 <type 'list'> [{u'time': u'0.004', u'sql': u'QUERY = u\'SELECT "RANGE_STATUS"."I
510 <type 'dict'> {'GetDiskFreeSpaceEx': <built-in function GetDiskFreeSpaceEx>, 'SetThr
510 <type 'dict'> {'GetDiskFreeSpaceEx': <built-in function GetDiskFreeSpaceEx>, 'SetThr
370 <type 'list'> [<weakref at 01CF5030; to 'type' at 1E228030 (type)>, <weakref at 01CF
types:
8625     <type 'function'>
3778     <type 'tuple'>
3128     <type 'dict'>
1672     <type 'list'>
1661     <type 'cell'>
1440     <type 'weakref'>
1351     <type 'wrapper_descriptor'>
1103     <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
888  <type 'type'>
734  <type 'getset_descriptor'>
```

WARNING : 27/12/2014 05:54:37 PM :

```
refs:
53295   <type 'list'> [{u'time': u'0.004', u'sql': u'QUERY = u\'SELECT "RANGE_STATUS"."I
9500    <type 'dict'> {'TAPE_DRIVE_FORMAT': -1610612736, 'SLE_ERROR': 1, 'IMAGE_REL_I386_SEC
8410    <type 'list'> [('200', '343045', 1321), ('200', '343046', 1322), ('200', '343047', 1
1578    <type 'dict'> {'logging.atexit': None, 'django.core.files.errno': None, 'django.test
1567    <type 'list'> ['mem_top', 'mem_top', 'datetime', 'datetime', 'sys', 'string', 'os', 
749 <type 'list'> ['A. HISTORY OF THE SOFTWARE', '==========================', '', 'Pyth
688 <type 'dict'> {'FILE_SYSTEM_ATTR': 2, 'GetDriveTypeW': <built-in function GetDriveTy
688 <type 'dict'> {'FILE_SYSTEM_ATTR': 2, 'GetDiskFreeSpaceEx': <built-in function GetDi
510 <type 'dict'> {'GetDiskFreeSpaceEx': <built-in function GetDiskFreeSpaceEx>, 'SetThr
510 <type 'dict'> {'GetDiskFreeSpaceEx': <built-in function GetDiskFreeSpaceEx>, 'SetThr
types:
8625     <type 'function'>
3778     <type 'tuple'>
3130     <type 'dict'>
1675     <type 'list'>
1661     <type 'cell'>
1440     <type 'weakref'>
1351     <type 'wrapper_descriptor'>
1103     <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
888  <type 'type'>
734  <type 'getset_descriptor'>
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that in my Django settings I had Debug=True . . . Turning it to False solved this issue. With Debug=True django internally builds a list which I was seeing as having excessive reference counts.

Comment: It is also important to remember that when running with DEBUG turned on, Django will remember every SQL query it executes. This is useful when you’re debugging, but it’ll rapidly consume memory on a production server.